# Working with names in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a spreadsheet to keep track of my players on my team. I would like to sum all of their individual times playing regardless of who they played (different players).

Is this possible?

Also, I would like for the data to be nested in the same column as their names appear.

Is this also possible?

If these actions can be performed, could you please provide me with the means to accomplish the tasks?

Comment: Can you be more specific? can you give us screenshots of as to how the table you are making looks?

Answer (score 1):

If the names are in one column and the times in another the sumif() formula works well:

> **SUMIF(range, criteria, sum_range)**  Adds the cells specified by a given criteria. Range is the range to which the criteria are to be applied. Criteria is the cell in which the search criterion is shown, or the search criterion itself. In the criteria section, you can use a question mark (?) to match a single character or an asterisk (*) to match a sequence of characters. If you'd like to find an actual question mark or asterisk, you can type a tilde (~) before the question mark (?) or asterisk (*). Sum_range is the range from which values are summed, if it has not been indicated, the values found in the Range are summed.

The other option is a [pivot table](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1272898). Which is more complex.

If the names and data are in the same column, a lot more work will be needed.